# How to force UIWebView to read NSHTTPCookie

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiwebview, nshttpcookie

I have a `UIWebView` that shows a login page. The user fill user and password and after the login the page save a `NSHTTPCookie` in the app sandbox.

With this line of code `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]` I can read all my cookies and using its in the code.

The problem is that when I reload the webView (e.g. when I create a new webView to show another page of the site) the web view doesn't read the cookie and show the login page again.

So the user can't stay logged in and this cause the user tap username and password for all pages that he want see.

How can I force the webview to read the stored cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the web view delegate, implement the `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` delegate method, create a new request with the cookie headers manually added, and load that instead of the original request.

Comment: Your solution sounds really smart... but can you add more details and show me an example ? thanks